# MongoDb C# concurrency issues with upsert

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a quite simple method for upserting an entry in a collection:

```
    public void UpsertEntry(string collectionName, Entry entry)
    {
        var collection = GetCollection(collectionName);
        var filter = Builders<Entry>.Filter.Eq(x => x.Key, entry.Key);
        var update = Builders<Entry>.Update
            .SetOnInsert(x => x.Id, ObjectId.GenerateNewId())
            .SetOnInsert(x => x.Key, entry.Key)
            .Set(x => x.LastUpdated, DateTime.Now)
            .Set(x => x.Data, entry.Data)
            .Inc(x => x.Version, 1);

        var result = collection.UpdateOne(filter, update, new UpdateOptions
        {
            IsUpsert = true
        });
    }
```

The collection has a unique index on Key.

I'm calling the UpsertEntry method in a Parallel.For loop

```
        Parallel.For(0, 100, i =>
        {
            entry.Key = $"key+{i}";
            UpsertEntry(coll, entry);
        });
```

I'd expect to get 100 record inserted, but instead I receive a `E11000 duplicate key error collection: TestDB.test::c7 index: key_1 dup key: { : "key+1" }`. Why am I experiencing concurrency issues? What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it and it has nothing to do with the driver itself. I didn't noticed I was re-using the same instance of the class Entry :-)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is saying that there's already a record with null. In other words, it means that you already have one with the same key represented in the collection

The relevant documentation for this:

> If a document does not have a value for the indexed field in a unique
>   index, the index will store a null value for this document. Because of
>   the unique constraint, MongoDB will only permit one document that
>   lacks the indexed field. If there is more than one document without a
>   value for the indexed field or is missing the indexed field, the index
>   build will fail with a duplicate key error.
>
> You can combine the unique constraint with the sparse index to filter
>   these null values from the unique index and avoid the error.

unique indexes

> Sparse indexes only contain entries for documents that have the indexed field, even if
>
> > the index field contains a null value.

In other words, a sparse index is ok with multiple documents all having null values.

Comment: Thanks, I know what the error message says, but if you look at the code, the key is an incremental. If a key is found is upserted, but something is going wrong in the driver itself with concurrency.